# How to prove that ab $\le \int_{0}^{a} \phi(x) dx + \int_{0}^{b} \phi^{-1}(y) dy$

Tags: inequality

How to prove that if $\phi: [0, \infty) \to [0; \infty)$ continuous and strictly increasing function. Then there is an inverse $\phi^{-1}$ and for all positive $a, b:$

$$ab \le \int_{0}^{a} \phi(x) dx + \int_{0}^{b} \phi^{-1}(y) dy.$$

I think i can prove it graphically, but not sure if this prove is rigorous.

[image]

Clearly that ab is less than sum of areas of green and violet triangles.

Comment: Just draw it! It's obvious.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg is my drawing correct?

Comment: @Yola: Your drawing is correct _for that particular choice of $\phi$_, but you haven't drawn all possible functions, and can't hope to, for obvious reasons. Instead, use the structure of your picture to guide an analytic proof: I'd suggest substituting $y = \phi(x)$ in the second integral and integrating by parts.

Comment: The image encapsulates the essential idea. The curve $y=\phi(x)$ goes from the origin to infinity and is not bounded. Thus, given $a,b>0$ without loss of generality, assume $b<\phi(a)$. Look at the region under the curve from $0$ to $a$ and add the region to the left of the curve from $0$ to $b$. The two regions together include the rectangle $ab$ as shown in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\phi$ is bijective and strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$, we have $\phi(0)=0$.

Let $\displaystyle g(t)=tb-\int_{\phi^{-1}(0)}^t\phi(x)dx$. Then

$$g'(x)=b-\phi(x)\begin{cases}>0 \quad \text{if}\quad x<\phi^{-1}(b)\\ <0 \quad \text{if}\quad x>\phi^{-1}(b)\end{cases}$$

So $g$ attains its maximum at $x=\phi^{-1}(b)$.

In particular,

\begin{align*}
ab-\int_{\phi^{-1}(0)}^a\phi(x)dx=g(a)\le g(\phi^{-1}(b)) =b\phi^{-1}(b)-\int_{\phi^{-1}(0)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)}\phi(x)dx
\end{align*}

Let $y=\phi(u)$. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_0^b\phi^{-1}(y)dy&=\int_{\phi^{-1}(0)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)}u\phi'(u)du\\
&=\left[u\phi(u)\right]_{\phi^{-1}(0)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)}-\int_{\phi^{-1}(0)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)}\phi(u)du\\
&=b\phi^{-1}(b)-\int_{\phi^{-1}(0)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)}\phi(u)du
\end{align*}

Therefore,

$$ab-\int_{\phi^{-1}(0)}^a\phi(x)dx\le \int_0^b\phi^{-1}(y)dy$$

As $\phi(0)=0$,

$$ab\le\int_0^a\phi(x)dx+ \int_0^b\phi^{-1}(y)dy$$