# To find $\int_{0}^{a}f(x) \ \mathrm dx+\int_{0}^{b}g(y) \ \mathrm dy$ where $g = f^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

> Let $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous strictly increasing function and $g=f^{-1}$. Let $a,b$ be distinct positive numbers. Then:
>   $$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) \ \mathrm dx+\int_{0}^{b} g(y) \ \mathrm dy$$
>
> A) $\ge ab$
>
> B) $<ab$
>
> C) always equals to $ab$
>
> D) always equals to $\frac{af(a)+bf(b)}{2}$

**My attempt**

If we use Leibniz integral rule we get,
$[af(x)]_{0}^{a}+ [bg(y)]_{0}^{b}$ thus we get $af(a)+bg(b)$ what now?

Comment: If you assume there is such a result you can just start out with a trivial example (for $f$), derive a hyppthesis from this and try to prove that.

Comment: If you want to use anything, you probably want $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I would start by drawing a picture (and noting that $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ for the integrals to make sense).

Comment: The answer is A. I answered before. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263626/how-to-prove-that-ab-le-int-0a-phix-dx-int-0b-phi-1y-dy/2263695#2263695

Comment: This is the integral version of Young's inequality. Google it, you will find a proof in the wiki article.

Comment: Thank you for the help @StubbornAtom